# How to monitor data usage on iOS from an app?

Tags: ios, ios5

There are a few similar questions on SO, but none directly answer this question: how can an app programmatically monitor the data usage of other apps?

For instance, at the end of the month, we would like a report that shows Chrome used X MB of data and Yelp used Y MB of data. It seems possible since companies like http://www.onavo.com/ are doing it now.

But our understanding is that apps are sandboxed on iOS and unable to monitor the data usage of other apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't legally possible. DataMan Pro tried to do it, and got away with it for a while, but Apple caught them and the app was thrown off the AppStore. It's back now, but without that capability.

Onavo works by setting up a proxy server. It knows how much data a browser uses because the data passes thru their server. It isn't measuring anything on the device; it's talking to their server.

Comment: thanks, @matt. how does it force all apps to pass through its proxy server?

Comment: You configure your settings to use a VPN.